# What early design decisions are important for creating "performant" multiplayer games?

Tags: multiplayer, performance, online

I want to create online games and focus on the performance from the beginning.

I searched on the internet, but didn't find any an particular answer concerning the design level or development level aspect, such as

---

- Design Patterns,
- Protocols,
- Techniques,
- Data transfer(games state) ,
- Formats(JSON/serialization)

;

which are crucial to create high performance online games can most of the articles are talking about hardware consideration,  but you know that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Your question is too broad. I think you need to narrow and pick performance in a particular area, i.e. latency vs. rendering vs. whatever.

Comment: Why do people USE random UPPER CASE to get POINTS across, you look like a serial killer sending notes to the police =P  The reason you don't find anything specific is because ALL games are MADE with performance in mind.  it's like trying to ask a fish about water.

Comment: Edited. But I also think this is too broad a question.

Comment: "Why do people USE random UPPER CASE to get POINTS across" where.. what... no idea; self assumption...  "because ALL games are MADE with performance in mind" So what they do when they have "performance" in mind and that is the Question...

Comment: Your edit doesn't really make the question any less broad. Try to ask [specific, directed questions about an actual problem](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) rather than questions where you could expect a litany of answers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a chinese programmer.We usually transfer Packet like this:
Length,Type,Data
and Length is short in C/C++,Type short,Data is raw string(binary data).
We did not serialize anything but just put the C/C++ struct into the Data,because doing this can get a good performance.
and,if you want to serialize your object into Packet,you should try [protocol buffer](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) or [thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/).They are scalable and high performance.

And,performance is a big topic.The basic idea is having performance problem,you should get the Hot Code,and fix them.

I am takling with you about the same thing, right?